# why google maps v2 not display in emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

I developed a project that include Google maps V2 and Be run in my emulator and display map very well. But today when run this project emulator don't display map . only show me a white screen white zoom buttons ,
I use google_play_services (V 18) in my project
and install Google Play Services 5.0.89 in my emulator
please help me 
thanks

Comment: any error messages such as "error contacting google servers" or so in your Logcat??

Comment: Are you using the api key corresponding to the debug keystore? Check that pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check your meta-data api key.

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your API key" />
```

Comment: I checked it and it is correct

Comment: Did you try in real device ? Are you include google_play_service ?

Comment: yes But I have same problem yet